# How to apply stroke around a curvy image in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to put an offset/stroke like outline/border around this kitty (which will be same in width, like stickers).

First I wanna remove this box around this PNG. how can I do it?
Second how can I convert it into an shape? and put stroke around in it?

I want to do it in Illustrator.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: That's a raster image. Illustrator is a vector image editor. So, you'd need to either draw the line around the image (using the Pen tool), or use auto tracing.  The box round the PNG is the bounding box of the image. It's not an object - only shows what you have selected.  If you select something else it will not be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not really conceptually work this way. It works a bit differently, but its equivalent in the end.

> First I wanna remove this box around this PNG

You cant do that, thats the image square it will always be there. What you instead do is you use a clipping mask to hide parts of the the image the box. The box is still there because the raster image is that box. A raster image can only be a box no way around that.

> Second how can I convert it into an shape?

Again conceptually you can't. what you do is you make a shape and hide parts of the image. You can off course use image tracing to make the shape, expand it and apply that to a copy of the image*, but I suggest you just draw it.

> and put stroke around in it?

Once you made a shape you can put a stroke on it.

* Because image tracing consumes your image.

Answer (score 3):

As already said by others, Illustrator doesn't allow you to remove the rectangular box of a PNG (I do not mean the blue bounding box which shows the image is selected), you can only make those pixels transparent which are outside the cat by inserting a clipping or opacity mask.

If your image is a PNG, it may already have a transparent background and nothing is needed to be made transparent,  but we cannot see it from your low-information screenshot.

I guess you do not get any essential benefits by working in illustrator. It will not make your kitten photo sharper, no matter it's a vector program. You can work as well in Photoshop.

In the next image I have separated from your screenshot (=layer 1, now hidden) the cat. It was so blurry and cropped that I guessed some areas. The separated cat is in layer 2.

[image]

I held the Ctrl key pressed and clicked the cat icon in the layers panel. That selected the cat area.

The selection was expanded, in this case 15 pixels. One could also smooth it with Refine Edge, but I skipped it.

A new layer was inserted below the cat. The selection was filled with a color. I used your green, but white probably would be the wanted one. That's the apparent stroke around the cat:

[image]

Comment: Nicely done using the expanded selection without drawing a stroke.